# Problem with "every" method in prototype function

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I've faced the following problem: the `every` method in my function returns `undefined` so `ableToMoveAll` function returns falls no matter what. Please, look at the following piece of code and help me with it:

```
var SQUADS = [];

function MilitaryUnit(name, maxHealth, maxEnergy){
    this.squadName = name;
    this.squadMaxHealth = maxHealth;
    this.squadCurrentHealth = maxHealth;
    this.squadMaxEnergy = maxEnergy;
    this.squadCurrentEnergy = maxEnergy;

    this.travel = function(dist){
        if (dist > this.squadCurrentEnergy) {
            alert("You can't go this far");
        }
        this.squadCurrentEnergy -= dist;
    }
    this.ableToMove = function(dist){
        return this.squadCurrentEnergy >= dist;
    }
}

var squadOfHorses = new MilitaryUnit("Horses", 50, 100);
SQUADS.push(squadOfHorses);
var squadOfSoldiers = new MilitaryUnit("Soldiers", 40, 50);
SQUADS.push(squadOfSoldiers);
var squadOfMachines = new MilitaryUnit("Machines", 100, 50);
SQUADS.push(squadOfMachines);

Array.prototype.ableToMoveAll = function(dist){
    return this.every(function(el){
        el.ableToMove(dist)
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the `every` method returns `undefined`, but the callback that you passed to it. You forgot the `return` statement:

```
return this.every(function(el){
    return el.ableToMove(dist)
//  ^^^^^^
});
```

Comment: *""every" method in my function returns 'undefined'"*. but `every` can never return `undefined`. so something is not correct about this question.

Comment: @dfsq That's what I explained, and it's the reason why I posted this as community wiki and voted to close the question.

Comment: Or an ES6 one-liner : `Array.prototype.ableToMoveAll = dist => this.every( el => el.ableToMove(dist) )`

Comment: Sorry for troubling you all. I really forgot the return statement.